# What's the equivalent of "SELECT SYSTEM_USER" in Linq

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I can get the identity of the currently logged in SQL Server user by using the `SYSTEM_USER` value, but is there a way to do this via [linq](/questions/tagged/linq) somehow? I'm looking for something like the below:

```cs
var query = from u in dataContext.Users
            where u.domainname == dataContext.system_user
            select u.fullname;
```

Using something like `Environment.UserName` won't work in the event a non-domain user authenticates via VPN, and querying via a separate statement is undesirable because I'd like to use just one statement to get the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling system functions can be done by creating new functions in the database which can be mapped further in the ORMs. It depends then on the ORM capabilities regarding to mapping user database functions.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnSystemUser () returns varchar(120)
AS
BEGIN
    return (select SYSTEM_USER)
END
```

LINQ2SQL and EF will create a single SQL statement for the following LINQ query.

```
var query = from u in dataContext.Users
            where u.domainname == dataContext.fnSystemUser()
            select u.fullname;
```

Comment: Perfect: this accomplishes *exactly* what I was looking for: early-binding and a strongly-typed return, all in one statement. (Didn't even think of the potential of SQL functions!)

Answer (score 0):

LINQ itself knows nothing about your database so no. If you're talking about LINQ 2 Entities (as some keywords in your code sample imply) you may be able to use one of the [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx) overloads (or one of its relatives) with your explicit SQL statement.

As an alternative, you could parse the connection string to get the user's log on details. I believe the [`SqlConnectionStringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.aspx) class should be able to tell you the user name and password of the user used to connect to the database if you aren't using Windows auth.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    class System
    {
        public string SystemUser { get; set; }
    }

   var query = dataContext.ExecuteQuery<System>("select SYSTEM_USER AS 'SystemUser'");
```

Comment: This doesn't give me Linq syntax, but I do get strong types in return, which is probably in the end what I'm looking for the most, so thanks for this snippet.

Comment: @ionden: I'll be checking in to see if there's any other useful insight on this topic over the next day or so, but so long as this is the best answer after then, I'll definitely mark as accepted.